# Apache Tomcat hang after "Initializing started..."

Tags: java, tomcat

Following are the startup log messages:

```
Check if Algo ant logger exists
Found Algo logger, starting with Algo ant logging
Buildfile: $ALGOWEBAPPS_HOME/bin/algowebapps-control.xml
Deleting:$ALGO_TOP/algowebapps/webapps/
        acm.war,acm470help.war,awl.war,dmcfg.war,Navigator.war,mdc.war,Visualizer.war
Copying 7 file to $ALGO_TOP/algowebapps/webapps
Deleting directory $ALGO_TOP/algowebapps/webapps/awl
Copying 1 file to $ALGO_TOP/algowebapps/webapps/ROOT
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path...
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:25 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12001
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:26 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8888
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1145 ms
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive Navigator.war
Load details in $ALGO_TOP/algowebapps/webapps/Navigator//MetaTables.xml
        Loaded 11 tables & views
Load details of db jdbc:oracle:thin:@UAT4
Load details of db jdbc:oracle:thin:@UAT4
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive mdc.war
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive acm.war
INFO: GridServlet - ==> initializing GridServlet processing
INFO: TreeServlet - ==> initializing TreeServlet processing
==> initializing LoaderServlet
INFO: AjaxStoreServlet - ==> initializing AjaxStoreServlet processing
INFO: ConfigStoreServlet - ==> initializing ConfigStoreServlet processing
INFO: ActionDataServlet - ==> initializing Ricos HTTP Servlet Executer
INFO: ExecuterServlet2 - ==> initializing Ricos HTTP Servlet Executer
INFO: ValidationServlet - ==> initializing ValidationServlet processing
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive acm470help.war
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive awl.war
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive dmcfg.war
2017-09-26 22:18:33,525 DEBUG [dmcfg] Installing into composite=com.algorithmics.log.provider.DailyLogFileProvider com.algorithmics.log.provider.CompositeLogProvider
2017-09-26 22:18:33,533 DEBUG [dmcfg] File path 'log' is relative - prepending ALGO_TOP=/opt/bns/alreu4/Algo/ALGO_TOP com.algorithmics.log.provider.DailyLogFileProvider
2017-09-26 22:18:33,534 DEBUG [dmcfg] Opening file '$ALGO_TOP/log/dmcfg-default-sbuvvrwm471-2017-09-26.log' om.algorithmics.log.provider.DailyLogFileProvider
2017-09-26 22:18:33,541 DEBUG [dmcfg] Installing into composite=com.algorithmics.log.provider.ConsoleLogProvider com.algorithmics.log.provider.CompositeLogProvider
Sep 26, 2017 10:18:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive Visualizer.war
Initializing started...

<<<It hangs here indefinitely>>>
```

Below is what is expected to follow in a normal startup:

```
[[
Initializing finished...
Sep 26, 2017 10:37:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig     deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Sep 26, 2017 10:37:48 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-12001
Sep 26, 2017 10:37:48 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443
Sep 26, 2017 10:37:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7637 ms
]]
```

Is downloading Tomcat cource code and enable Tomcat debug mode the only choice to identify the root cause of such issue? But I have no access to the source code of those applications running in Tomcat (I can decompile the jar files in war files though it's a tedious). or there might be better way to figure out the cause?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the deployed application start up. You would have to enable debug logging for the application and see the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

You might also check the context.xml for the webapp and see if it's connecting to an external resource, e.g., a database.  The log message explicitly mentions an Oracle jdbc driver, it may be hanging while trying to create a database connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is now mitigated by a upgrade of NFS server to V4.